How to make QPushButtons fill the window vertically in QGridLayout
I´m new to Qt and i´ ve made a simple widget application, a chess timer. I would like my buttons to fill the entire window. They do horizontally but not vertically:

/*mainwindow.cpp*/

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QGridLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    stopWatch_A = new StopWatch(this);
    stopWatch_B = new StopWatch(this);

    btnA = new QPushButton(stopWatch_A->m_time->toString("mm:ss:z"));
    btnB = new QPushButton(stopWatch_B->m_time->toString("mm:ss:z"));

    connect(stopWatch_A->m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this->stopWatch_A, &StopWatch::startStopWatch);
    connect(stopWatch_B->m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this->stopWatch_B, &StopWatch::startStopWatch);

    connect(stopWatch_A->m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::updateTimeA);
    connect(stopWatch_B->m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::updateTimeB);

    connect(btnA, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::btnAClicked);
    connect(btnB, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::btnBClicked);

    resetBtn = new QPushButton("Reset");
    connect(resetBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::resetCLicked);
    
    /*BUTTONS PLACEMENT*/
    QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout(ui->centralwidget);
    layout->addWidget(btnA, 0, 0);
    layout->addWidget(btnB, 0, 1);
    layout->addWidget(resetBtn, 1, 0, 1, 2);
}

Is there a way to specify that the buttons should fill the whole area?
I' ve posted the part of the code in which i define the buttons, in case i can edit the question and add all the files.

QPushButton has a Fixed vertical sizePolicy(). Change that to Preferred or even Expanding.
